# Add inline onclick Method using Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have an div element:

```
<div
  class="button-primary"
  id="product-cl-add-cart"
  @click="displayApproval($event)"
  >
  Add To Cart
</div>
```

This div calls the method:

```
displayApproval($event)
```

In js Vue `createApp` I setup this method-

```
const displayApproval = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  Fancybox.show([{
    src: `
            <div>
                <h3>Please look over the custom text to make sure its correct. <br>
                    All sales are final on custom items.</h3>
                <button onClick="function closeFancy(){ Fancybox.close()  } closeFancy(); return false;" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: rgb(247, 185, 162);">Go Back To Confirm</button>
                <button onClick="function continue(e){ addToCart(e)} continue(${event});  return false;" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: rgb(211, 254, 211);">Continue With Order</button>
            </div>`,
    type: "html",
  }]);
}
```

I add the method `onClick` like so because just `addToCart()` didn't work for me.

The method addToCart is also in my setup-

```
const addToCart = (event) => { 
  // do something 
}
```

Basically, I need the above to work and pass the event.  For some reason, it's not working for me.  I've tried the above and also:

```
onClick="addToCart(e)" 
onClick="addToCart()"
```

I set the above from a few suggestions I read online.  I'm not entirely sure about how to set this up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) is JS statement. Use some other name for your function.
2. if your `addToCart()` function is defined inside the Vue `setup()`, then you have to call it over the Vue instance.

Like this:

```
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

and then

```
onclick="function cont(e){ vm.addToCart(e) }; cont(event);"
```

Otherwise, you have to make `addToCart()` function global to call it directly.

3. I don't think you really need the wrapping functions. It works well without them.

```
<button onclick="Fancybox.close()" 
<button onclick="vm.addToCart(event)"
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = { 
  setup() {
    
 const displayApproval = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
    
  Fancybox.show([{
    src: `
<div>
    <h3>Please look over the custom text to make sure its correct. <br>
        All sales are final on custom items.</h3>
    <button onclick="Fancybox.close()" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: rgb(247, 185, 162);">Go Back To Confirm</button>
    <button onclick="vm.addToCart(event)" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: rgb(211, 254, 211);">Continue With Order</button>
</div>`,
    type: "html",
  }]);
}
    const addToCart = (event) => { 
      alert('Continue With Order')
      console.log("addToCart(): " + event.target)
    }

    return { displayApproval, addToCart }
  }  
}
const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css"
/>
<div id="app" v-cloak>  
<button class="button-primary"
  id="product-cl-add-cart"
  @click="displayApproval($event)">
  Add To Cart
</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```